# Does $a_{n_m} \to l, m \to \infty$ for each sequence $n_1 \mid n_2, \; n_2\mid n_3, \;n_3 \mid n_4 , \dots$ imply that $a_n \to l, n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $l\in \mathbb{R}$ are such that, for any strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $(n_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the property that $m_1$ divides $m_2$, $m_2$ divides $m_3$, $m_3$ divides $m_4$, ..., it follows that $a_{n_m} \to l, m\to\infty$.

> Is it true that $a_n \to l, n \to \infty$?

A positive answer should imply a different proof line to this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481934/does-f-n-f-1-to-0-where-f-n-is-the-mean-of-f-over-a-uniform-partition) (there we have to deal with a sequence with values in a pseudo-metric space, but the idea is the same).

Any proof or counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Consider the sequence $a_n=1$ if $n$ is prime and $0$ otherwise. Then clearly any subsequence $a_{n_m}$ will be of the form

$$n_1\text{ composite or }n_1=1\text{ and }n_2\text{ composite}\Rightarrow a_{n_m}=\{0,0,0,...\}$$

$$n_1=1\text{ and }n_2\text{ prime }\Rightarrow a_{n_m}=\{0,1,0,...\}$$

$$n_1\text{ prime}\Rightarrow a_{n_m}=\{1,0,0,...\}$$

depending on $n_1$ and $n_2$. Since every subsequence member of the subsequence $n_m$ must be composite, and $a_n=0$ for composite $n$ we conclude every subsequence converges to $0$. However, it is obvious that $a_n$ does not converge to zero as it is $1$ at every prime.